# build dlls using Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dllimport

I want to build dlls using Visual Studio which I want to use as functions in Matlab.

While doing so I have used declspec(dllimport) function...but I get compilation error LNK2019: unresolved external sumbol?

Appreciate your help.

```
#ifdef PRC50CONTROL_EXPORTS
#define PRC50CONTROL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define PRC50CONTROL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


int PRC50CONTROL_API SetPRC50Gain(double inGain);
```

Comment: You need to show us what you have tried.

Comment: It sounds like you should do a Google search for a step-by-step tutorial, that's not what this site is for.  See [tour] then [ask] then [mcve]

Comment: @Zym: To add C++ code to your question, click the edit button below your answer.  In the editor, you'll see a toolbar.  In the toolbar, there's a button with two curly-braces.  That creates a region inside your answer for code -- it will get syntax highlighting, and it won't get processed for formatting characters.  There's another toolbar button that would let you insert an image, but you don't have 10 reputation yet so it won't work for you.  Instead, just leave us a link and a note that it's ok to pull the image into your question; someone with enough reputation will edit and do it for you.

Comment: Now please remove the picture and add text, thanks. Pictures of code are useless.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int PRC50CONTROL_API SetPRC50Gain(double inGain);
```

You have the return type before the __declspec()

Move it to

```
PRC50CONTROL_API int SetPRC50Gain(double inGain);
```

Also, obviously, make sure you have

```
PRC50CONTROL_EXPORTS
```

defined in your header of the library you're exporting the symbols from.